# Solve the challenge of overlapping points in Matplotlib/Pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graphics

I want to plot two class of points with python with different colors , but when I plot them with `scatter` those points which overlap other ones obscure them. 
What I mean is I want to show both of the points (e.g green & purple) in one fixed point.

My Code :

```
plt.scatter(range(1,len(tp_labels)+1),[x[1] for x in tp_labels ],color = 'purple')
plt.scatter(range(1,len(tp_labels)+1),[x[2] for x in tp_labels ],color = 'green')
```

As you can see the green overwrites the purple on overlapped points.

I would appreciate your solutions.

Comment: How would you like to plot to look like instead? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to tinker with your alpha settings in order to develop the amount of transparency that best suits your particular circumstances. In matplotlib/pyplot the alpha setting determines the transparency of the item you are plotting. Its values can range as follows (0.0 transparent through 1.0 opaque).

Check out the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) and you'll see that you have the option to adjust the alpha setting for almost anything in matplotlib/pyplot up to and including the legends and even the plot background. This should solve your issue regarding subsequent plots obliterating earlier ones.